# Running a distributed graph BGL code

Tags: boost, graph, distributed-computing

I need to distribute a Graph across some nodes (i.e. perform distributed programming), using BGL.

I tried to run this sample code I found:
https://github.com/boostorg/graph_parallel/blob/master/test/named_vertices_test.cpp

However, I was getting a huge amount of error, which mainly stated "undefined reference to `boost::serialization..."

I wish to know what dependencies do I need to install for the code to run. And also, how to compile my code.

**Note**: Normal BGL code is running perfectly fine. 
I have installed OpenMPI 2

Do I need to build Parallel BGL as well ? The recent version of BGL contains distributed algorithms, I think.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You should link boost lib when you compile; add

```
-lboost_graph_parallel -lboost_mpi -lboost_system -lboost_serialization
```

to your  link command, plus a `-L` option for wherever your Boost libraries are